# Mail with PHP/Xampp

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost

I have in XAMPP an Shoppingcart, when I order an product and I click on Secure Checkout, then I would like to receive an email with Localhost/Mercury or Thunderbird.

Only, what I do/change in the php/php.ini folder or the Sendmail folder, I don't receive any mail.. I follewed this link, but noting work unfortenelty.. How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?

How Can I reveive easy an email, when I order something after I click on Secure checkout? This is my managecartform.php file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"/>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>XXL Computer winkel</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "cookiefuncties.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "shoppingcartfuncties.js"></script>
<link href='css/main.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='all' />
<style type='text/css'>

form label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<b><p>Overzicht van Uw Shoppingcart:</p></b>
<p>
<form action="mailto:test@localhost.nl"
enctype="text/plain" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);"
method="post">
<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <td class="td"><b>Product ID</b></td>
        <td class="td"><b>Merk</b></td>
        <td class="td"><b>Model</b></td>
        <td class="td"><b>Prijs</b></td>
        <td class="td"><b>Aantal</b></td>
        <td class="td"><b>Totaal</b></td>
        <td class="td"><b>Verwijder</b></td>
        </tr>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                cartWeergeven();
                bestellingsFormInvullen();
            </script>
            </table>
            <br /><br />
            <table border="1" width="500">
            <tr>
            <td>Firstname: <input type="text" size="18" name="firstname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Surname: <input type="text" size="18" name="surname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>E-mail: <input type="text" size="49" name="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <a href="xxlcomputers.html"><img src="images/terug.jpg" /></a>
            <a href="xxlcomputers.html"><img src="images/reset.jpg" onclick="removeAlleCookies();" /></a>
            <input type="image" src="images/checkout.jpg" onclick="location.href='succes.html';">
        </form>
    </p>
</body>
</html>

<form action="?" method="post">
<ul>   
    <li>    
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </li>

    <li>    
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="email" />
    </li>

    <li>    
        <label for="topic">Name:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="Acer">Acer</option>
            <option value="Toshiba">Toshiba</option>
        </select>
    </li>

        <li>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="42" rows="9"></textarea>
    </li>

    <li>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Congratulation for your second self duplication, anything wrong with 1.) [Mail with Secure Checkout Localhost (XAMPP)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23814629/367456) and 3.) [How make Order Tracking with PHP/MySQL possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23856582/367456)

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP (on Windows platform) does not work with the SMTP port 25 unlike as defaulted on Linux/Other platforms so try installing Test Mail Server Tool (http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/). Once installed, and opened alongside your application, The tool simulates the server sending out mail as requested.